# Why is an Ideal a subset of Rad(I)

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Why is $I \subseteq Rad(I)$?

I don't quite get this.

Comment: The definition of $\mathrm{Rad}(I)$ that I know makes this pretty straightforward. What definition are you using?

Comment: It's straightforward from any definition of the radical.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $R$ be the ring containing $I$.  Generally the definition of the radical is
$$\mathrm{Rad}(I) = \{x \in R \ | \ x^n \in I \ \text{for some positive} \ n\}.$$
If $x \in I$ then for $n = 1$ we have $x^n \in I$, hence $x \in \mathrm{Rad}(I)$.

The other definition that's common is that $\mathrm{Rad}(I)$ is the intersection of all prime ideals containing $I$.  But if every set being intersected contains $I$ then the intersection contains $I$, hence $\mathrm{Rad}(I)$ contains $I$.